# How can i get Calibri and specified width of table display?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am new to `HTML`, I search on Google and I found some code snippets. I am trying to place a table in my Outlook email body:

### HTML

```html
<html>
     <body>
         <table style="
         margin: 10px" 
         bordercolor="black"
         cellspacing="0"
         cellpadding="2"
         width="300"
         border="1">
             <!--Content here -->
         </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

well, its working fine, but my requirements have changed and I want to have the following:

- Specified table `width` **(7.5 inch)**
- I want to specify the `Calibri` font
- I want the `font-size` to be **11**.

Comment: I don't know much about HTML emails either, but I'm guessing it would just be something like: `<table style="width: 7.5in; font: 11pt Calibri,Tahoma,Verdana;">`. Aside from that, you should probably put your styles in a `<style>` block and avoid inline CSS.

Comment: Are you only sending to Outlook, or do you want compatibility with all email clients?

Answer (score 4):

Hi and welcome to the wacky world of html emails.

Calibri isn't a common font, so declaring it, would not show on all devices/OS's that don't have it natively. You'd have to set fallbacks as I've done in the example below.

Margin also has limited support and is ignored by Outlook 2013 completely, so avoid that in favor of padding or empty tables

Declaring in inches would not work also, so you'd have to test what pixel size would work/equate for you when printing.

Here is a basic table though:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td border="1" style="padding:10px; font-family: 'Calibri', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #000000;">
      Your content here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML emails are a very strange beast indeed. I spend a lot of my time each week writing them. Some advice: A table width of `656` works pretty well, and I wouldn't go a whole lot larger. I know that width prints on standard 8.5" x 11" paper well enough. We use it in all of our HTML emails and it usually renders well everywhere. We test on gmail, Outlook 2007, and the default mail application for OSX.

As @John mentioned Calibri is a Microsoft font, so it will only come through on machines that have it installed. Which should work out for you okay, as long as you also have a websafe back up available.

```
<table width="656" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: 'Calibri', Arial, sans-serif ;font-size: 11px;">Some content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another HTML email pointer. If you add any `<a>` and would like for them to not be the standard blue color, make sure you assign a `style="color: #(color hex);"` for each one.

Best of luck. Writing HTML emails can be really frustrating some days.